# DxaNoOutputCache and NoCache not working for custom controllers

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We have a custom controller for some custom functionality which basically calls a web service to fetch some data, depending on certain input parameters from end users. We have enabled output caching for the website but don't want this particular functionality to be cached. Our page has the standard elements like header, footer, banner, etc which are served by CMS and then results are displayed via our custom controller.

In order to achieve this, we have tried using DxaNoOutputCache, NoCache, Cache with a duration of 1 but nothing seems to be working and the page/results get cached every time.

Any thoughts or any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this attribute?  
[NoCache]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Comment: Yes, we tried that (after noticing it in adminController) but we received an error when used "Nostore" saying "child actions cannot use that" and also the duration should be greater than 0. So we tried with [NoCache] [OutputCache(Duration = 1, VaryByParam = "*")]  and it would still cache everything

Comment: It's not mandatory to pass that attribute, what is the behavior if you are not passing?

Comment: Its still cached, it looks like "NoCache" has no affect

Comment: Is that your custom controller getting the call or not? if that's not getting then your route configuration something wrong or handler level something goes wrong, or your custom page request also goes to default page controller and getting cached?

Comment: Please edit your question to update your custom controller class? give some pointers to how your implementation you are trying access, enable trace logs to troubleshoot the issue, or run a web application in locally and try to debug?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `DxaNoOutputCache` attribute is intended to be used on View Models, not on Controllers.

The other cache attributes are not DXA-specific; these are general ASP.NET MVC attributes influencing the general ASP.NET MVC output caching behavior. See, for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_caching.htm